# Many applications refuse to connect to Internet (Spotify, PC game pass games, Discord...)

Tags: windows-11, kaspersky, discord

I got MANY applications that refuses to work correctly since few weeks. Before I throw the compputer out of the window, I would like to see if I can get some help.

Most relevant info from my computer

- Windows 11 (upgraded from Windows 10 more than a year ago)
- Kaspersky Total security

Issues:

- PC Xbox game pass: cannot check if a program is up to date, all games refuses to start. (I even unsubsribe...)
- Discord: Update failed loop
- Epic games: cannot connect, games don't start

I already tried to disable Kaspersky for few minutes, result is same...

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I use the first command and this what I see:
'Error: 87

The checkhealth​ option is not recognized in this context.
For more information, refer to the help.'

Comment: Are you running it in an elevated CMD?

Comment: @harrymc of course

Comment: OK, If I use PowerShell in adminsitrator mode, I was able to run the commands.
First said that the system is healthy, second told me that he had to fix some corrupted files.
STILL, my programs are still crashing...

Comment: You have a corruption in Windows. I suggest https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/

Comment: I don't have Windows installation media... Can I just download it from Microsoft server? (I never try to fix Windows like that....)

Comment: Yes, you could and you should download it only from Microsoft. Read the article, it explains everything. Take good backups, because undoing corruption can leave holes in Windows.

Comment: @harrymc It's Working! If you want to transfer the corruption fix in an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The poster experienced strange effects and `sfc /scannow` found errors
in Windows.

In my experience, SFC is very good at detecting inconsistencies in
Windows software, but is not very good at repairing them.

To bring Windows to a consistent state with all components being of
the same level requires to do
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

The Repair Install has indeed fixed the problem of the poster.